# Using coin toss to decide winner among 3 children

Tags: probability

I have 1 chocolate and 3 children. I want to decide which child gets the chocolate using a toss of a fair coin. I also want each child to be equally likely to get the chocolate. How do I do this?

Comment: Toss the coin twice.  $HH$ is a win for $A$, $HT$ for $B$, $TH$ for $C$ and $TT$ means you try again from scratch.

Comment: You need additional constraints, for example, with minimal number of tosses. Otherwise, you can come up with many possibilities. For example: toss the coin 10 times for each child and count the number of H. The one that has the most wins. If two are tied, repeat the process for them. If all tied, redo from start.

Comment: You can't guarantee exact fairness with a finite number of flips, though you can get close. @lulu's answer is a good approach but you can see that there is no upper bound the number of flips.

Comment: I agree with @YJT. Otherwise take the coin and split the bar into 3 pieces. :D

Comment: To be fair, each kid needs 1/3 chance to win.

Your coin is binary, that is H or T. Expressing 1/3 in binary is an infinite sum.

Force kids to choose different 2 toss coin sequences and then do as lulu told you. At least that is a solution and it can be proven that the probability for infinite number of 2-toss games is zero.

Comment: The same argument in the linked question applies here, noting that $\gcd(5,7)=\gcd(2,3)=1$